# Unrecognized value: 'terraform_plan' in a condition

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

In my ADO pipeline I have stage called terraform_plan and am referring it to another stage called manual_validation. But am getting the below error.

> An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Unrecognized value: 'terraform_plan'. Located at position 70 within expression: and(in(dependencies.manual_validation.result,'Succeeded','Skipped'), terraform_plan.outputs['terraform_plan_job.produceVar.TERRAFORM_PLAN_HAS_CHANGES'], 'true')). For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996

Pipeline code is given below.

```
stages:
  - stage: terraform_plan
    displayName: Terraform Provisioning - Plan
    variables:
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    jobs:
      - job: terraform_plan_job
        displayName: Plan and Persist
        steps:
          - checkout: self
```

referring the terraform_plan in below stage condition.

```yaml
     - stage: manual_validation
       displayName: Manual Validation Phase
       condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.RequireManualValidation }}', true), eq(dependencies.terraform_plan.outputs['terraform_plan_job.setvar.HAS_DESTROY_CHANGES'], 'true'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
       pool: server
       jobs:
         - job: manual_validation_test
           displayName: Please approve in order to proceed
           timeoutInMinutes: ${{ parameters.ApprovalTimeoutMinutes }}
           steps:
             - task: ManualValidation@0
               inputs:
                 notifyUsers: ${{ parameters.PlanApprovers }}
                 instructions: the planned changes to the infrastructure
                 onTimeout: reject
     - stage: terraform_apply
       displayName: "Terraform Provisioning: Apply"
       variables: 
       condition: and(in(dependencies.manual_validation.result,'Succeeded','Skipped'), terraform_plan.outputs['terraform_plan_job.produceVar.TERRAFORM_PLAN_HAS_CHANGES'], 'true'))
       pool:
         vmImage: ubuntu-latest
       jobs:
         - job: terraform_apply_job
```

I tried using dependencies and "stageDependencies" but both are not working

Comment: YAML is whitespace sensitive. Is that actually the way your YAML is formatted? Please ensure the formatting is *exact* when posting here.

Comment: It is not syntax error, but when I posted the code here I trimmed it.

Comment: You're making it more difficult to help you by not posting syntactically valid YAML. Please ensure your YAML is formatted correctly.

Comment: Also, the error message you provided doesn't correspond to the condition in the YAML snippet you provided.

Comment: I tried using dependencies and "stageDependencies" but both condition gives me same error.

Comment: Daniel, thank you. I have corrected the yaml syntax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252705/discussion-between-wonderhost-and-daniel-mann).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, you need to modify the condition in the terraform_apply stage.

```
condition: and(in(dependencies.manual_validation.result,'Succeeded','Skipped'), eq(dependencies.terraform_plan.outputs['terraform_plan_job.produceVar.TERRAFORM_PLAN_HAS_CHANGES'], 'true'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious syntax error. Look at what happens if you break down the expression slightly.

```
and(
 in(
   dependencies.manual_validation.result, 'Succeeded', 'Skipped'
  ),
terraform_plan.outputs['terraform_plan_job.produceVar.TERRAFORM_PLAN_HAS_CHANGES'], 'true')
)
```

The parenthesis aren't even balanced. You probably wanted to write `eq(terraform_plan.outputs['terraform_plan_job.produceVar.TERRAFORM_PLAN_HAS_CHANGES'], 'true')`, but that's probably not going to work as-is; it probably does need to be qualified with `stageDependencies` and so forth.